# Save data to SkyDrive

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light, onedrive

I use MVVM Light Toolkit and I have two views - main and settings.

Main view

- data from users (ObservableCollection - SomeModel)

Settings view

- login to SkyDrive

I want to save data from collection to SkyDrive. What is the best or available solution?

- use messenger and send data as parameter from MainViewModel to SettingsViewModel
- get LiveConnectSession from SettingsViewModel and use it in MainViewModel (I would prefer this option or something similar)
- something else?

Thanks and sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use some kind of shared service, that will allow you to get/set `LiveConnectSession`. In the `SettingsViewModel` you can configure and set it, and then use it from any other `ViewModel`.

But if you do not want to add such service, then you can use your second approach.